# Restore dateRangeInput as empty

Tags: r, shiny

I can start a `dateRangeInput` with empty `start` and `end` in Shiny.

```r
dateRangeInput("date", "Date input", start = "", end = "")
```

After doing a selection inside this date range, when I try to

```r
updateDateRangeInput(session, "date", start = "", end = "")
```

It doesn't work. It works with other kind of inputs (see below).

Here's a reprex, when I click on go it put the date, when I click on go2 it does nothing.

```r
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    h4("Date:"),
    # Starting with an empty date
    dateRangeInput("date", "Date input", start = "", end = ""), 
    actionButton("go","go"),
    actionButton("go2","go2"), 
    # And an empty button
    textInput("text", "text"), 
    actionButton("go3","go3")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent( input$go , {
      # Will change the date accordingly
      updateDateRangeInput(
        session, 
        "date", 
        start = Sys.Date()-10, 
        end = Sys.Date()-5
      )
    })
    observeEvent( input$go2 , {
      # Does nothing
      updateDateRangeInput(
        session, 
        "date", 
        start = "", 
        end = ""
      )
    })
    observeEvent( input$go3 , {
      # Empties the text input
      updateTextInput(
        session, 
        "text", 
        value = ""
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: shinyjs::reset will do that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A date format seems to be needed. You can use `NA` instead of `""`.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    h4("Date:"),
    dateRangeInput("date", label = h5("Date input"), start = "", end = ""), 
    actionButton("go","go"),
    actionButton("go2","go2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent( input$go , {
      cat("go1\n")
      updateDateRangeInput(session, "date", start = Sys.Date()-10, end = Sys.Date()-5)
    })
    observeEvent( input$go2 , {
      cat("go2\n")
      updateDateRangeInput(session, "date", start = NA, end = NA)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `reset()` from `library(shinyjs)` instead of `updateDateRangeInput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    h4("Date:"),
    # Starting with an empty date
    dateRangeInput("date", "Date input", start = "", end = ""), 
    actionButton("go","go"),
    actionButton("go2","go2"), 
    # And an empty button
    textInput("text", "text"), 
    actionButton("go3","go3")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent( input$go , {
      # Will change the date accordingly
      updateDateRangeInput(
        session, 
        "date", 
        start = Sys.Date()-10, 
        end = Sys.Date()-5
      )
    })
    observeEvent( input$go2 , {
      reset("date")
    })
    observeEvent( input$go3 , {
      # Empties the text input
      updateTextInput(
        session, 
        "text", 
        value = ""
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion! Sébastien Rochette gave an answer in pure shiny so I've accepted his.